# Tensorflow predict likeliness of two sentences to go after each other

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I use AWS Textract to extract text from documents, however, some sentences are ripped apart which I need to put back together using Tensorflow. I'm quite new to TensorFlow, therefore I don't know what model configuration I need to achieve this. Here are some examples of what I need the model to predict. This is the input:

```
[
 [
  {
   "part": "I think that"
  },
  {
   "part": "TensorFlow is great."
  },
  "label": 1
 ],
 [
  {
   "part": "I'm"
  },
  {
   "part": "computer in the room."
  },
  "label": 0
 ],
]
```

I need the model to predict the label, how likely it is for these two strings to go together.

What model architecture do I need to do this?

Comment: try transformer

Comment: It's probably easier to use some existing language model instead of training your own; however try to check if the API gives you the bounding box coordinate, which might make the task easier.

Comment: @Andrey What do you mean by transformer? Huggingface? Which model does what I need?

Comment: @FrederikBrammer yes. Use sequence classification model. E.g. BERT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sequence classification model, e.g. `BERT` from Huggingface transformers.